# Как  нетипизированный указатель привести к типизированному виду?

Tags: указатели, c++

```
void* pvbits;
```

Я точно знаю, что pvbits указывает на начало массива из 600*800 элементов типа структуры, состоящей из 3-ёх переменных типа BYTE. Далее я пишу:

```
typedef TRGBTriple pixa[480000];
pixa* pix;
```

Как теперь сделать так, чтобы pix указывал туда же, куда и pvbits. 
Я пробовал так:

```
pix=pvbits; //Error: not an allowed type
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pix=static_cast<pixa*> (pvbits);
```

Comment: О, да, так даже правильней.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а что за угловые скобки? Они применяются только для static_cast? Когда их нужно использовать?

Comment: Почитайте про шаблоны

Comment: @mikillskegg, спасибо

Comment: Вот раздражает меня обилие букв, которые (на самом то  деле они не нужны) требует компилятор в С++ (и длиннющие описания в документации). 

Исключительно недоверчивая программа.

Comment: Ну, по идее можно использовать С-стайл преобразование типов...........

Comment: А какие буквы здесь не нужны? На самом деле, такое приведение более безопасное, особенно в случае приведения указателей. POD типы приводятся как в С-стиле, а вот указатели проверяются. void** приводится спокойно, а вот string** к int** - фиг. А при С-style - запросто. Иногда это важно, особенно в шаблонах.

Comment: Есть замечательный reinterpret_cast  - он приведет любой указатель к любому.

Comment: @mikillskegg, вот я и говорю, что C-style приведения типа - это то, что нужно. Я просто достаточно кратко говорю компилятору - "я знаю, что делаю". Если это приведение (к адресам не относится) компилятор не может сделать, скажем, структуру хочу привести к double, то он мне это сообщит.

Я согласен, что   **dynamic_cast** может оказаться полезной проверкой, а вот остальные C++-style приведения - это только лишний текст.

Также я понимаю, что целью их введения в язык является раннее выявление ошибок, но не уверен, что это оказало положительное влияние на качество *run-time* кода.

Comment: А мне угловые скобочки нравятся. Стильненько так...

Comment: @mikillskegg: строго говоря, угловые скобки в static_cast не имеют ничего общего с шаблонами.

Comment: Соглашусь с @avp.
По-моему, самым опасным является `const_cast`, т.к. он снимает константность и запросто может привести к UB. А самыми полезными являются `boost::lexical_cast` и `numeric_cast` оттуда же

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так: `pix=(pixa*)pvbits;`

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, `pixa` - это массив из `TRGBTriple`, а `pix` - это **указатель на массив** из `TRGBTriple`. Т.е, чтобы `pix` указывал на тот же массив, что и `pvbits`, нужно сделать `pix=(pixa*)&pvbits`. А чтобы не городить ошибочных преобразований, нужно приводить не к массиву элементов, а к указателю на элемент: `TRGBTriple*pix = (TRGBTriple*)pvbits`.

Comment: похоже, "бревна в глазу" ни кто не видит :)